# How to route on googlemap from csv file?

Tags: android, google-maps, csv

I want to development an application like this:

There is a csv file containing the coordinates as follow.

```
30.6674,36.8925 
30.6651,36.8926
30.6649,36.8923
...
```

I want to route the way on google maps api by getting the coordinate information from csv file.
How do I do this, can you give sample link or any suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

loading csv file content in an array:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=225845

passing an array of addresses (or coordinates) to the API:
[how to use the google maps api with greasemonkey to read a table of addresses and trace the route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894996/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-with-greasemonkey-to-read-a-table-of-addresses-an)

--- EDITED [28/10/2011] ---

here: [Loading an array from a .txt file? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905214/loading-an-array-from-a-txt-file-android)
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668507/trying-to-load-a-list-of-overlay-positions-from-file

Comment: RASG, your link for javascript, I need an android sample.

Comment: thanks for answer but examples are not exactly the way I want.